# Node.JS Append Array and Convert to JSON

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, for-loop

I have the below that runs a few functions to grab different data and i am trying to create/append to an array to "create" a new array that i can then JSON.stringify and pass to the Jade view, i seem to only be able to get the "k" variable of the two loops it does and outputs as "coin1coin2" with the "" instead of a JSON array with the balance and addresses (multiples) after each coin name.

```
// list all wallets //
app.get('/wallet', function(req, res){
    var coins = app.get('coins');
    var addresses = "";
    for (var k in coins) {
        addresses += k;
        console.log('Coin: ' + k);
        //console.log(k+' => '+coins[k]);
        connect(coins[k]);
        client.getBalance('44abc0a80102', 6, function(err, balance) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            addresses += balance;
            //console.log('Balance: ' + balance);
        });
        client.getAddressesByAccount('44abc0a80102', function(err, address) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            addresses["address"] += address;
        });
    }
    console.log(addresses);
    res.render('wallet', {
        title: 'Wallet',
        address: JSON.stringify(addresses)
    });
});
```

In the Jade view i am just doing `p= address` to show the full array so i can at least see what i am getting before creating logic in the view to loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your `for` loop is synchronous, whereas your `client.getBalance` and `client.getAddressesByAccount` calls are (almost definitely) not.

When your `for` loop finishes, your `client.getBalance` and `client.getAddressesByAccount` operations are still in progress, so they haven't had a chance to populate your `addresses` thing yet. Thus it is empty when it's passed to the templating system.

You probably want to use something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)'s [map method](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) to do this instead. It'd look something like this:

```
// list all wallets
app.get('/wallet', function(req, res){
    // array? object?
    var coins = app.get('coins');

    async.map(coins, function(coinId, cb) {
        // ???
        console.log('Coin: ' + JSON.stringify(coin));

        // not sure what this does!
        connect(coin);

        client.getBalance('44abc0a80102', 6, function(err, balance) {
            if (err) return cb(err);

            client.getAddressesByAccount('44abc0a80102', function(err, address) {
                if (err) return cb(err);

                return cb(null, {
                    address: address,
                    balance: balance,
                });
            });
        });
    }, function(err, addresses) {
        // note that we only act on an error here
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        // [{address: ..., balance: ...}, ...]
        console.log(addresses);

        res.render('wallet', {
            title: 'Wallet',
            address: JSON.stringify(addresses),
        });
    });
});
```

The `addresses` value will be an array of `{address: ..., balance: ...}` objects. I'm not sure what you were expecting it to be, since at one point you treat it like a string, then you treat it like an object.